# If $(a_n) \to 0$, then applying the algebraic limit theorem, what is $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} \frac {1+2a_n}{1+3a_n - 4a^2_n}$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

If $(a_n) \to 0$, then applying the algebraic limit theorem, what is $ \lim_\limits{n\to\infty} \frac {1+2a_n}{1+3a_n - 4a^2_n}$.

Would just be able to do : $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} \frac {1+2(0)}{1+3(0) - 4(0)}$.

$\lim \frac {1}{1} = 1$.

Comment: Why?  $a_n \not \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: My mistake, I meant to write $(a_n) -> 0$, not $(a_n) -> a$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: The function $f(x) = {{1+2x}\over{1+3x-4x^2}}$ is continuous, so $f(a_n)$ converges towards $f(a)$.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, this is also the exercise 2.3.4 (a) from Understanding Analysis By Abbott.

$\lim{\frac{1+2a_{n}}{1+3a_{n}-4a_{n}^{2}}} = \frac{\lim{(1+2a_{n})}}{\lim{(1+3a_{n}-4a_{n}^2)}}= \frac{1+2\lim{a_{n}}}{1+3\lim{a_{n}}-4\lim{a_{n}^{2}}}=\frac{1+2*0}{1+3*0-4*0}=1$, as $(a_{n}) \to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

If $(a_n)→a$ and $1+3a-4a^2 \not=0 (a\not=1; a \not = -\frac 14)$, then $ \lim_\limits{n\to\infty} \frac {1+2a_n}{1+3a_n - 4a^2_n}=\frac {1+2a}{1+3a - 4a^2}$

Comment: And fortunately $1+2a$ is not a factor of the denominator.  But you should add that this works provided $a$ is not $1$ or $-1/4$.